# Quartz.NET/Castle Windsor Integration XmlInterpreter exception

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, quartz.net

Having downloaded the latest source of the Quartz.NET integration project to reproduce the error I am experiencing I am concerned that the source SampleApp produces the same issue.

https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/QuartzNetIntegration

When starting the program I am attempting to configure the container like so:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

Which before even reaching my quartz installer, fails with an exception of:

"facility elements expects required non blank attribute type"

[image]

I've traced this (I hope) to this portion of the app config (taken from the SampleApp of the github source):

[image]

Whereas if I change the config to this it passes this step of the config but fails to register two instances of the Quartz Facility (as it should)

[image]

Any suggestions how to get this up and running?

Cheers.

Comment: Please, try to post code as text instead of its screenshots :)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/castle-project-devel/hn_gpBqf1cA/discussion

Answer (score 0):

I'd make things to be like that:

```
<facility id="startable.facility" type="Castle.Facilities.Startrable.StartableFacility, Castle.Windsor"/>
<facility id="quartznet" type="Namespace.Castle.QuartzFacility, Namespace">
    <globalJobListener>
        <!-- the rest-->
</facility>
```

and in code:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());  
// container.AddFacility("quartznet", new QuartzFacility());
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the wiki says to register the Quartz.NET facility like this:

```
<castle>
  <facilities>
    <facility id="startable.facility" type="Castle.Facilities.Startable.StartableFacility, Castle.Windsor"/>
    <facility id="quartznet" type="Castle.Facilities.QuartzIntegration.QuartzFacility, Castle.Facilities.QuartzIntegration">
      <quartz>
        <item key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName">XmlConfiguredInstance</item>
        <item key="quartz.threadPool.type">Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz</item>
        <item key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</item>
        <item key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">Normal</item>
        <item key="quartz.plugin.xml.type">Quartz.Plugin.Xml.JobInitializationPlugin, Quartz</item>
        <item key="quartz.plugin.xml.overwriteExistingJobs">true</item>
        <item key="quartz.plugin.xml.scanInterval">10</item>
      </quartz>
    </facility>
  </facilities>
</castle>
```

http://docs.castleproject.org/Contrib.Quartz-Net-integration.ashx

This is because from Windsor 3.0 the type attribute is now required for the facility configuration/
https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/commit/40f8eefb16226fb279389b732ab89c8c55853ba5